# want to change button image in iPad when user click

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

As we know hover effect dose not allow in iPad, but i want to change button image when user click on the button. Below css work fine except iPad and iPhone device.

```
.back-btn {
background: url("images/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.back-btn:hover, .back-btn:active {
background: url("images/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -10px transparent;
}
```

Thanks
AV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to look for the `touchstart` event for the iPad to recognize it, and you can set the hover event otherwise.  With a little browser sniffing - boom you should be good to go. (jQuery-wise)

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "hover";

$(".back-btn").bind(event, function(e) {
    $(this).css('background', 'url("images/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -10px transparent;');
});
```

[More information on **html5 touch events** here.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/)

Comment: its work fine, but once we click on buttons that click image stay as it is, is it possible that when user release that button than original image will appear?

Comment: somthing like this effect   http://jsfiddle.net/3JBaZ/  

onclick bg color change but when user release it original css replace, perfect example which i want same for the iPad

Comment: Use `"touchend"` to set the (what is basically 'blur') event, and you'll be all set :)

Answer (score 0):

`:active` Class is only for Anchors, Not for buttons. You can make a anchor look like a button and then you can use this class for your operation.

Have a look at [**This Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3JBaZ/)